# HERE maps get circle radius in miles

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

When I create a circle, the radius is in meters, but I want to get the radius of the circle in miles, is it possible to do that?

I don't want to convert meters to miles with formulas, I want the value of the circle to already be converted when I get the radius

```js
    theCircle.getRadius() = //result should be in miles 
    theCircle.setRadius(/*  value in miles */ );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setUnitSystem()` method.

[Related Document](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/maps/map-scale-bar-changing-from-the-metric-system)

Comment: I already did that, but I still get the radius in meters :(